# Assigning values to a block in a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I am trying to change a block within a two-dimensional numpy array by inserting pasting another 2-dim array. The sample below gives me unexpected behavior:

```
import numpy as np
M=np.ones((4,4))
print(M)
S=[0,1]
print('to be set to zero: ',M[S,:][:,S])
M[S,:][:,S]=np.zeros((2,2))
print('after setting to zero: ',M)
```

I would expect the upper left corner of M to become zeros. However I get

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
to be set to zero:  [[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
after setting to zero:  [[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

It seems that I can extract the upper left block but not write to it. I get the expected behavior if I replace the line

```
M[S,:][:,S]=np.zeros((2,2))
```

with

```
M[0:2,:][:,0:2]=np.zeros((2,2))
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: You're setting entries on a copy.

Comment: `M[S,:]` creates a copy; `M[0:2,:]` a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy advanced indexing [ix_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

```
M[np.ix_(S,S)]=0

M
Out[622]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```